# VueJs:Laravel- Add loading spinner that shows in front of the page while all data is loading

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, axios

I want to add the loading spinner until data is not loaded. For this I have created a loading component.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="preloader" v-if="show">
        <div class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "PreloaderComponent",
    data: () => ({
        show: true
    }),
    mounted(){
        if(Boolean(this.show)) this.showToggle()
    },
    methods: {
        showToggle(){
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.show = false
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.preloader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

And Import this component view in our dashboard.vue so that, once all the widgets in dashboard is loaded the spinner disappers . but by adding this code spinner not disappers after all the widgets are loaded.
So i am looking for the solution to Add a black spinner and slightly dim the background while the data on the dashboard is loading that should work for all future API calls we add, so i am trying to find the solution that would solve this problem automatically with Vue.

Finding a solution for how I can add a loading spinner to the dashboard until the pag not loads properly.That only shows the loading spinner for 1 second in all cases;  If the data takes longer to load from the API, then the spinner could disappear after 1 second while data hasn't loaded yet.  Or if the data loads really fast, the user might be stuck waiting for the full second to complete.  The first issue is more concerning, since we need to keep the spinner up until everything has loaded.

Comment: I would make a loader that works on html only, that way you don't even need to wait for vue to be loaded. You can put it inside `<div id="app"><!-- loader here --></div>`. Vue will override what's inside the div when loading

Comment: but it not works half of my dashboard is loaded half is still in progress. @Lk77

Comment: then you will need to hide it/remove it when you don't need it anymore

Comment: I wanted the automatic solution

Comment: I don't think your code is correct, isAxiosRequesting is not a valid event for window

Answer (score -1):

Here is a loader i'm using :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 44 44">
    <style type="text/css">
          <![CDATA[
            g circle {
              stroke: #fff;
              stroke-width: 3;
            }
            g circle {
              opacity: 0;
              animation: size cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 1.8s infinite,
                         opacity cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 1.8s infinite;
              transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            }
            g circle:last-child { animation-delay: 0.9s; }
            @keyframes size {
              0% { transform: scale(0); }
              100% { transform: scale(1); }
            }
            @keyframes opacity {
              5% { opacity: 1; }
              100% { opacity: 0; }
            }
          ]]>
    </style>
    <g fill="none">
        <circle cx="22" cy="22" r="20"/>
        <circle cx="22" cy="22" r="20"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

it's a plain svg loader that will works regardless of js/vue, or even loading of external css,
and there is many more svg loaders to choose from on the internet.

Those loaders will load instantly, and are perfect for that.
If you need to, you can also put the loader outside of the #app div,
so you can decide when you want to remove it, if your app takes time to load.

You will perhaps need a black or white background, and you will perhaps need to center it on your webpage and make it absolute positionned.

i took the loader here : https://samherbert.net/svg-loaders/

Comment: In Loder.vue If i can add id app and import this component in another vue file that will work ?

Comment: yes that will work, but you will have no loader before vue load. What you can do is to have the same loader in vue and in the div, so when vue load, it put the loader in the div, which is the same as before, so the end user will not see the difference

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `<![CDATA[`? What will that change? What does it do?

Comment: cdata is not really necessary here, i think it does nothing, since it's html not xml, i'm using it but i'm not the author of it, i was thinking that it was from https://samherbert.net/svg-loaders/ but i'm not so sure about it.

Comment: I found it, the original file is here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SamHerbert/SVG-Loaders/next/svg-css-loaders/puff.svg it's quite old, so perhaps that's why. There might be better svg loaders out there, it's more an example than anything else.